# Netbeans IDE | Centered TitleText on Custom TitleBar

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, titlebar

i'm creating a custom title bar, but the problem is i can't make the text to be centered on JFrame because i have 3 buttons in pnlTitle.
I tried to drag & drop the button to inside JLabel, but it still outside the JLabel. How to achieve this ?

[image: My Custom Title Bar]

Comment: This is kind of tricky, because you need to allow the label to occupy the entire width, but still get the buttons to appear on the right - my personal approach might be to use a `GridBagLayout`

Comment: can you please tell me more details about it Sir ? i tried to change pnlTitle Layout to GridBagLayout but nothing change, its still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* This is a massive cheat...

[image: Centered title]

So, this example basically exploits `GridBagLayout`, which will allow the "title" label to occupy the entire width of the available space in the container and allow the buttons to laid out along the right edge at the same time

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            // This is a space to force the buttons
            // to the right edge.
            // You might be able to play around with the constraints
            // for b1 to basically get the same affect
            add(new JLabel(), gbc);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            JLabel label = new JLabel("This is the title");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label, gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(new JButton("B1"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("B2"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("B3"), gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 44);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use border layout where buttons are in east and title in center.

Hope that helps.

-- Updated ----

Here is the piece code that I was trying to share:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class TestSwing {

public static void main(String...s) {

    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    JPanel heading = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Button3");
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    buttons.add(button1);
    buttons.add(button2);
    buttons.add(button3);
    heading.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel title = new JLabel("Title",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    title.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    heading.add(buttons,BorderLayout.EAST);
    jframe.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jframe.add(heading,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel blankPanel = new JPanel();
    blankPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,40));
    heading.add(blankPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
    heading.add(title,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jframe.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Output Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: And the text would still be offset by the width of the buttons on the right

Comment: ensure that east and west have the same width, this will ensure that text is center

Comment: No, it won't, the text will "appear" off centre because it's constrained to the available space of the centre panel, which will be the width of the parent container minus the width of the east component, the OP will end up with nothing more then they already have

Comment: i tried this (3 buttons on east, label on center), but now it only showing 1 button. and yes the label width is still didn't fully sized to JPanel

Comment: After using the above layout,  you can use JLabel as JLabel title = new JLabel(TITLE"", SwingConstants.CENTER); and then title.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);